# Как сделать проверку на тип, чтобы цифры шли в один массив, а буквы в другой

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть переменная string result = Console.ReadLine(); и есть два цикла, int[] numbers; char[] names; Цикл прогоняет result по индексу и тип равен char. Как сделать проверку на тип, чтобы цифры шли в один массив, а буквы в другой.

Comment: Тип у всех одинаковый - ``char``. Но у цифр значение от 0x30 до 0x39, у букв (латинских) от 0x41 до 0x7A.

Comment: У класса `Char` есть набор [методов](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netframework-4.8#methods). Используйте их (`IsDigit`, `IsLetter` и т. п.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            string result = Console.ReadLine();
        List<int> numbersList = new List<int>();
        List<char> lettersList = new List<char>();
        char[] symbols = result.ToCharArray();
        for(int i = 0;i<symbols.Length;i++)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(symbols[i]))
                numbersList.Add((int)char.GetNumericValue(symbols[i]));
            else
                lettersList.Add(symbols[i]);
        }
        int[] numbersArray = numbersList.ToArray();
        char[] lettersArray = lettersList.ToArray();
```